# No Passport, but must transit Stansted Airport for flight to another EU country

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ryanair

Flying from Nuremburg, through Stansted to Rome on Ryan Air. Traveller has no passport but has a national ID for Germany. Is one required to transit Stansted if origin and final destination ports are in EU?

Comment: Now you know why that flight was cheaper lol.

Comment: If it's really cheaper to start by flying 500 miles in the wrong direction, then that's everything wrong with modern aeronautics right there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with aeronautics here... this has more to do with supply, demand, government subsidies, etc. Similar things exist in other modes of transport as well (trains, ferries...)

Comment: @Johnnyjanko: Okay, the modern aeronautics _industry_ then.

Comment: @JackAidley It's simply inflexibility of supply. The plane is going to fly those legs anyway and incur nearly all of the costs, regardless if OP flies or not. They don't make planes (trains, boats, or busses) that are exactly 1 seat smaller. The airline rather make money than fly those seats empty.

Comment: Please explain how you will die if you don't travel that way?  Otherwise what makes it a "must"?

Comment: @Johnnyjanko  Plenty to do with *not* costing CO2 emissions however.

Comment: @user71659: Sigh.... Flying or not does make a difference in the long term. If enough people notice that it's unnecessary to fly from Nürnberg to Rome, and especially moronic to fly from Nürnberg to Rome with a layover in London, airlines might stop proposing such flights or connections. There are new night trains connecting Germany to Italy, by the way.

Comment: @EricDuminil You missed my point. The airline can't add or remove seats from the direct flight unless the average load changes by at least 20-30 seats, since that's the increment of plane sizes. If one more person wants to fly, having them take the circuitous route is more efficient than adding 29 empty seats. Airlines do a much better job with load factors than other forms of transport: pre-COVID Ryanair's load factor was 95-96%. Is the average train 95% full? Not at all.

Comment: "must transit without passport" is not a question. A question would be *"Can an EU national[?] fly from one EU country to another via UK (Stansted) without a passport?"* as in *"will the airline let that passenger board without the required documentation for transiting via the UK?"*. To which I think you already know the answer is no. (If you explain why the person doesn't have a passport (lost? stolen? asylum-seeker? other?) maybe that improves the question.

Comment: @user71659: And what is your point, exactly? That individuals cannot have any impact on demand and growth (or decline) of civil aviation, because they typically don't book 20 seats at the same time? If Ryanair notices often enough that a flight has a load factor below 90%, they might think about canceling it. "Is the average train 95% full? Not at all." Trains are for public transport: they should be available anyway. And they don't ride 1000km in the wrong direction, and don't release 100kg CO2 per passenger per hour, ...

Comment: @EricDuminil trains fare in Germany works the same way as airplane. The less available places, the more the ticket costs. A Frankfurt-Berlin train connection may costs 150€, while a flight costs 50€.
If DBahn uses the extra profit to give more money to the employees through a pension scheme investing in a coal mine...
To be the devil's advocate: counting all the environmental impact from high-speed railways (often it is a low-capacity highway), I am not sure focusing on the CO2eq emissions from planes is meaningful ... but it is a wider discussion I do not want to have here.

Comment: @EricDuminil Those trains are much, much more expensive than the flights though (and I know - I regularly take them both because of environmental concerns and because I prefer traveling by train), I think it's unreasonable to expect people not to react to the obvious incentives, even if I would also much prefer if a lot more traveling was done by train.

Comment: @DenisNardin Sadly, you're right. My faith in humanity decreases a bit every time I compare train and plane prices. Still, it shouldn't prevent us from noting that Nürnberg->Stansted->Rome is a ridiculous trip. Not traveling at all is the least expensive option, but it might not be the most popular on travel.stackexchange.com. And traveling by train can be really enjoyable indeed.

Comment: @EricDuminil What people miss and lots of calculators miss is that trains are ridiculously labor intensive. A single 1-cm crack on a rail can derail a train and kill hundreds. Every single km of rail has to be perfect. Result: huge numbers of staff, their cost, and their on CO2 emissions. Also, trains are very heavy: a single passenger car is ~40 t equal to an empty 737. Consider the load factor again, trains never run 95% full on average. Somehow running a plane half full is a huge environmental issue, but running a train 10% full is a non-issue. There's huge amounts of greenwashing here.

Comment: @user71659 all the activities around train travel can be de-carbonized (and have been, already, in some places). Air travel, not at all. Trains are simply much more carbon-efficient at transporting people.

Comment: @user71659: Sure, let's ignore the fact that a 737 needs to fight against gravity during all the flight, while even a large passenger car will have a coefficient of rolling resistance of about 1/500. Or that your planes also need a large infrastructure on the ground. There's enough data comparing environmental impact of planes/trains/cars/bicycles already. It just seems that you're not ready to accept the conclusions.

Answer (score 35):

Yes a passport is required. You now need a passport to enter the UK and Stansted does not have an international lounge area, so you have to enter the UK.

But before that you will also need to convince the airline that you have the right paperwork, and they know you need a passport for the UK, and they will not take the second flight in account as the airline can only see you entering the UK, and can not be sure you will take that second flight.

While some airlines are less strict, especially Ryanair is known to be more strict about passports and visa rules than even the countries they fly between and within.

Comment: My son travelled on an extended passport with me to the US some years back.  Immigration was not a problem but the airline was.  When you hear "I've never seen anything like this before" you know it is going to take a while.  They really don't want to deal with you not coming in so they have to bring you back.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't understand; what was the problem with your son's passport?

Comment: @gerrit it would expire too soon to be allowed in so I got its validity period extended. The physical passport just had a handwritten annotation saying this

Comment: Note that the airline benefits.  They sold the seat, then they deny boarding—and no refund because "it's not our fault you didn't have the proper documentation"

Answer (score 22):

Since October 2021, the vast majority of EU citizens now require a passport to enter or transit the UK. There are a few exceptions which generally only apply to EU citizens that live/work in the UK, which presumably is not the case here.

From the [European Union's website](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-nationals-living-uk/index_en.htm) :

> **I am an EU national without any status under the UK's EU Settlement Scheme**
>
> To enter or transit the UK you will need a valid passport,
> which must be valid for the duration of your stay in the UK. ID cards
> are not accepted.

This is true for all UK airports.

Stansted airport specifically is different to some other major UK airports in that it is not possible to transit between flights (even between international flights) without passing through immigration. In other words, it's not possible to transit "airside" - all passengers need to clear immigration and officially enter the United Kingdom.

The UK Government's website is a little vague on whether an ID card can be used for transit, but is very clear that one is required [when entering the country](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen).

EU citizens generally do not require a visa to transit the UK.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

You cannot use an EU, EEA or Swiss national ID card to enter the UK unless you meet certain criteria eg have pre-settled status. Stansted does not have an airside transit zone, you will need to clear Immigration https://www.stanstedairport.com/help/passenger-guides/connecting-flights/

Source: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visiting-the-uk-as-an-eu-eea-or-swiss-citizen